# PostGIS servers to increase power

Tags: postgis

I am currently working locally on my terminal.
I have Windows 10 x64, 12Go RAM, 428Go SSD, an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 2400 MHz, 2 hearts.

I need to use PostGIS to make some queries and filter my data.

My database contains 39 tables. My biggest table has 4 millions rows.
I run some cross join with my tables.

The trouble I have is that my queries are taking too much time (maximum query took 6h and returned only null values).

I developed a Python script to split my queries and run them each by each instead of all of them in a row, but it also failed.

So I am looking for a way to have more power. I have understood so far that I should use a server to do this, but I do not know any server or service of this kind.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have created the indices for all my tables. Then I ran the query creating the most trouble, which is:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1 = liste.my_bool
FROM(
    SELECT T1.id AS name,
        bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom, T1.geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.geom, T2.geom))) AS my_bool
    FROM table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.id
 ) AS liste
WHERE table_1.id = liste.name;
```

The `table_1` has 52630 entities and the `table_2` 2025.
The query returned `null` values for my `field_1` after one hour of loading. I then tried the subquery only and got this error message:

```
ERROR:  ERROR:  could not write the block 8568766 from temporary file : No space left on device
SQL state: 53100
```

I want field_1 to be True if the geometry of table_1 shares total or partial surface with any entity of table_2. This is why I need a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: did you do the usual postgresql tuning? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

Comment: what do you mean by "postgresql tuning" ? I did install PostgreSQL first and added the spatial extension, Postgis

Comment: did you look at the link? you need to adjust your postgresql install to get any performance

Comment: Your computer is just fine for using postgres. Probably your query does not use indexes (or you have none).

Comment: there is a lot more you can do to 'tune' postgres/postgis including building and maintaining spatial indexes so your searching/filtering goes much faster.

Comment: here is a good starting point for indexing and vacuuming http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Comment: try running the query on a small sample of rows to make sure the query is written properly and will actually return something other than NULL. The NULL issue can be unrelated to performance issues.

Comment: By cross join, do you mean a full Cartesian product that has no joins or where clauses? The computer looks fine. Indexes and optimization could be a problem and needs to be looked at (primary keys, joins on integers, etc.), but I am more suspicious of the logic in the SQL query. 4 million times 4 million becomes a very big number.

Comment: What @NateWanner says -- fix the query before worrying about hardware. Please, edit the question to show the output of EXPLAIN. Also, you can probably use [ST_Relate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html) to specify contains plus overlaps. Although, thinking about it, contains or overlaps is just intersects, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what @JohnPowell said in the comments, you can make a join that is based on a spatial intersection. If you have a spatial index setup, this should have much better performance than a cross join. If you do not have a spatial indexes, you can create them directly in PostgreSQL using SQL or use the QGIS DB Manager to create them with a GUI.

Example related to the table names in your question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.id AS name,
       True::boolean AS my_bool
    FROM table_1 AS T1
    JOIN table_2 AS T2
       ON ST_Intersects(T1.geom, T2.geom)
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine, the full cartesian product I was doing took like 1 hour and failed each time, your solution takes 3 secs, just one question : I do not understand the line `True::boolean as my_bool` and its links with the distinct and the join

Comment: I'm glad it works. The query only returns rows where there was an intersection. If I understood your query, you were returning either True or False for every entry. Because of the ST_Intersects join, there is never a False so I didn't see a need to calculate it, but you still want the True return (cast to type boolean) to feed into your table update (not part of the join). Without the table update, it's not necessary. Depending on your application, you may want to update all values to False in your table prior to running the update query, or run a separate SELECT/UPDATE ON NOT ST_Intersects.